# Confusion about PHP Non-Thread safe

Tags: apache-2.2, php, multi-threading

PHP 5.1.6 - Non-Thread Safe ( Thread Safety=**disabled** in phpinfo() ) 
Apache 2.2.3 - MPM **prefork**

Should I be using prefork or worker? If so is this an easy switch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should always use prefork with `mod_php`. Most Linux distributions do not allow to install `mpm_worker`-providing package with `mod_php`.